# How to make an array or arraylist of Rect

Tags: android, rect

I am going crazy trying to figure this out. I am trying to make an array or arraylist of Rect (rectangles) that I can update the coordinates and draw on the screen(to make them move).

Right now I have a separate class called Fire in which I make a new rectangle each iteration with the new coordinates in its own onDraw() method.  In the View's onDraw() method's first iteration I add a new Fire to an arraylist.

In the Fire class I have:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    moveF();
    Rect r = new Rect(_l,_t,_r,_b);
    canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
}
```

In the View class I have:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int i = 0;
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    if(i==0){
        fires.add(new Fire(20,100,40,120));
        i++;
    }
    for(Fire fire : fires){
        fire.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

I got rid of pointless parts of code, but this is the important stuff.  The Rectangle prints, however it prints all the previous locations as well and I don't understand why.  I have been trying to fix this forever and any help you guys could give would be greatly appreciated.  I was able to implement this in java easy, but android is giving me problems.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code, you are adding new rectangles to the list, and then drawing *each* rectangle. But from the description, it seems that you just want to draw a single rectangle, with updated coordinates.

Instead of creating a new Rect each time, reuse a rectangle and update its coordinates with `set(...)`.

A second problem is that you set `i=0` and then immediately check for `i==0`, which would be always true. Try something like this instead:

```
static final Rect rect = new Rect();

// your code here

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    moveF();
    rect.set(_l,_t,_r,_b);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

}
```

Comment: I'll check this out and post back with the results, I thought the if statement would make it so only one fire is created, but making a new Rect each time doesn't make sense.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Brian I saw your comment after updating my answer :)

Comment: Awesome! I changed it to rect.set(_l,_t,_r,_b);
and then moved the i=0 outside of the method and it works perfectly!

I hate having to ask for help, but you guys are amazing and I make far too many stupid mistakes haha.
thanks =)

Comment: @Brian we all use help. I'm glad it was useful. Please consider marking the answer as correct then (right next to the number, on the left).

Answer (score -1):

With each call to View.onDraw you create a new fire and add it to your list.
Then you iterate over all fires and draw them.
So you get more and more fires.
Do all fires move the same way or is there some random component?
It might be that you don't see the previous locations of one fire, but that there are many fires moving on the same path.

Do you want to have 1 fire moving around or more and more fires moving around independently?

Comment: Ideally I'll get multiple fires moving around independently.

Comment: OK, then your code spawning fire is fine. Does the canvas gets cleared at some moment? Maybe you are seeing the old locations, because the background is never erased and the new fires are just painted on top of the old ones?

Comment: Not sure if YOU need to erase or if the framework does that for you. Maybe this helps: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html  (also the comments about invalidate and postInvalidate)

Comment: I got it to work by changing it to rect.set(_l,_t,_r,_b);
instead, and also moving the i=0; outside of the method.  I'll check the link out tho I'm sure it is good to know, thanks for the help!